# Grouping JSON by 2 parameters

Tags: php, json, parsing

I wrote the code that selects data from database, groups array by 2 parameters (match_day and competition_id) and generates JSON

```
foreach ($result as $res) {
    $day = date('d', $res["match_start_time"]);
    $json["response"][] = array(
        "competition_id" => $res["competition_id"],
        "match_start_time" => $res["match_start_time"],
        "match_day" => $day
    );
}
$arr = array();
$arr["items"] = array();
foreach($json["response"] as $key => $item)
{
    if(!isset($arr['items'][$item['match_day']][$item['competition_id']])){
        $arr['items'][$item['match_day']][$item['competition_id']] = array();
        $arr['items'][$item['match_day']][$item['competition_id']]['league'] = $item['competition_id'];
        $arr['items'][$item['match_day']][$item['competition_id']]['day'] = $item['match_day'];

    }

    $arr['items'][$item['match_day']][$item['competition_id']]['matches'][] = $item;
}

$arr['items'] = array_values($arr['items']);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

This code gives me following JSON

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "cuefa": {
                "league": "cuefa",
                "day": "01",
                "matches": [
                    {
                        "competition_id": "cuefa",
                        "match_start_time": "1285873500"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "cuefa": {
                "league": "cuefa",
                "day": "30",
                "matches": [
                    {
                        "competition_id": "cuefa",
                        "match_start_time": "1285866000"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I can't remove competition_id inside of items array. How to change code to get following JSON?

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "block": [
                {
                    "league": "cuefa",
                    "day": "01",
                    "matches": [
                        {
                            "competition_id": "cuefa",
                            "match_start_time": "1285873500"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "block": [
                {
                    "league": "cuefa",
                    "day": "30",
                    "matches": [
                        {
                            "competition_id": "cuefa",
                            "match_start_time": "1285866000"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: you need to wrap block/cuefa to array because you get object not an array.

Comment: your json is not valid, validate json via validator http://jsonlint.com/ and then put valid json here https://www.functions-online.com/json_decode.html you'll see how your structure have to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this before the `json_encode`:

```
foreach ($arr['items'] as &$item) {
    $item = array('block' => array_values($item));
}
```